# Stream video to an ios app from a mongoDB using Gridfs-stream

Tags: ios, node.js, mongodb, swift, gridfs

I'm a relatively new programmer trying to create an ios video-streaming app in swift. I've written the backend in node.js and have a mongoose connection to a mongoDB. I've been able to upload videos to the database using the following code and gridfs

```
function (req, res, next) {
req.pipe(gfs.createWriteStream({ filename: 'filename'}));
res.send("success");
};
```

I'm attempting to stream the videos using the following code

```
    gfs.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function (err, file) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send(err);
    } else if (!file) {
        return res.status(404).send(' ');
    } else {
        res.header("Content-Type","video/mp4");
        res.header("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
        res.header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        res.header("Content-Length",file.length);

        var readStream = gfs.createReadStream({_id: file._id});
        readStream.on('open', function () {
            console.log('Starting download...');
        });
        readStream.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log('Loading...');
        });
        readStream.on('end', function () {
            console.log('Video is ready to play');
        });
        readStream.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('There was an error with the download' + err);
            res.end();
        });
        readStream.pipe(res);
    }
});
```

When I run a server on localhost and attempt to access the videos via google chrome, all I get is the default playback screen but no video. However, ultimately I am trying to playback on an ios app. When I try the same thing on swift (using the local host url passed in to mpmovieplayer), there is also no video playback. I know the get request is going through because my console outputs the proper response with the filesize. I have even been fiddling with alamofire on the front end and can see the hexadecimal representation of the video in the response data. Can anybody help with this code? Do I need to update my res.header to fit some IOS specification? Should I even be using alamofire at all for this? Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: Clarification: I am playing video back from a server, not live-streaming it, which I know is a different and more difficult subject.